# How include in the regex those lines that start with letter 'N' but exclude that start with 'N/A'

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, regular-expression

I have a file with many lines like this:

```
Table
$0.10
100
1
10


Chair
$0.12
N/A
7
5


Desktop
$0.08
86
7
3


Door
$0.00
N/A
7
3

Nails
$0.10
N/A
7
5

Sofa
$0.07
100
7
3

Stool
$1.00
0
7
5

Natural wood
$0.00
99
7
20

Carpet
$0.10
100
7
3
```

I want to merge lines around those that start with a letter. So the output must be:

```
Table   $0.10   100 1   10       
Chair   $0.12   N/A 7   5       
Desktop $0.08   86  7   3       
Door    $0.00   N/A 7   3       
Nails   $0.10   N/A 7   5    
Sofa    $0.07   100 7   3    
Stool   $1.00   0   7   5       
Natural wood    $0.00   99  7   20  
Carpet  $0.10   100 7   3
```

With this command `sed -E ':a;N;/\n[A-M|a-z|O-Zo-z]/!s/\n/\t/;ta;P;D' file` I get:

```
Table   $0.10   100 1   10       
Chair   $0.12   N/A 7   5       
Desktop $0.08   86  7   3       
Door    $0.00   N/A 7   3       Nails   $0.10   N/A 7   5    
Sofa    $0.07   100 7   3    
Stool   $1.00   0   7   5       Natural wood    $0.00   99  7   20  
Carpet  $0.10   100 7   3
```

So, How include in the regex those lines thar start with letter 'N' but exclude that start with 'N/A'?

Comment: `awk '$1=$1' RS= file`?

Comment: You could just make sure the second character is not a slash ex. `[A-Z][^/]` or `[[:upper:]][^/]`. But really I second @Cyrus suggestion ...

Comment: It doesn't work. It creates a line like this: `Door $0.00 N/A 7 3 Nails $0.10 N/A 7 5 Sofa $0.07 100 7 3 Stool $1.00 0 7 5 Natural wood $0.00 99 7 20`

Comment: @steeldriver, thanks for your answer I chaged the command to `sed -E ':a;N;/\n[A-Za-z][^/]/!s/\n/\t/;ta;P;D'`and it works.

Comment: As I cannot fully explain GNU awk's behaviour in conjunction with empty `RS`, here only as a comment: `awk '$1=$1' RS= FS='\n' OFS='\t' file`

Comment: @Cyrus you were close but it should be `{$1=$1}1`, not just `$1=$1` as the latter will fail when `$1` evaluates numerically to zero.

Comment: @EdMorton: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is why paragraph mode in awk exists. This will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' -v OFS='\t' '{$1=$1}1' file
Table   $0.10   100     1       10
Chair   $0.12   N/A     7       5
Desktop $0.08   86      7       3
Door    $0.00   N/A     7       3
Nails   $0.10   N/A     7       5
Sofa    $0.07   100     7       3
Stool   $1.00   0       7       5
Natural wood    $0.00   99      7       20
Carpet  $0.10   100     7       3
```

Everything above is idiomatic awk, here's what it means:

1. `RS=<null>` tells awk that your input is a set of records separated by blank lines (i.e. paragraphs).
2. `-F'\n'` tells awk that the input fields are separated by newlines (equivalent to `-v FS='\n'`).
3. `OFS='\t'` tells awk that output fields must be tab-separated.
4. `$1=$1` tells awk to recompile the current record replacing every FS (newline) with OFS (tab) between fields.
5. `1` is a true condition which invokes awks default action of printing the current record.

Comment: Seems that as these are `\n` separated then setting `-F` has no effect in this case.

Comment: @bu5hman that was supposed to be `\n`, not `\t`, fixed now.

Comment: That was what made me try it both ways and then found it works without touching `-F` at all. Nice wrinkle BTW

Comment: Without `-F'\n'` it'd convert the blank in `Natural wood` to a tab. It's just hard to see that because the tab lines up perfectly as it would with a blank in that particular string.

Comment: Indeed it does, lucky chance that the word was the right length. Probably why `-F=` works as well, no `null` in the lines?

Comment: `-F=` shouldn't work as it's settting FS to `=` and `\n` needs to be included in the FS chars for anything to look like it's working in this script. Maybe you mean `-v FS=`? What that does would be awk-version-specific as it's undefined behavior per POSIX so it may have been ignored in the awk you use.

Comment: No you are quite right. Reason was as I noted above for the wrong reason `=` isn't in the file so the split never occurs. My bad

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution thanks to steeldriver's recommendation:

```
sed -E ':a;N;/\n[A-Za-z][^/]/!s/\n/\t/;ta;P;D'
Table   $0.10   100 1   10       
Chair   $0.12   N/A 7   5       
Desktop $0.08   86  7   3       
Door    $0.00   N/A 7   3    
Nails   $0.10   N/A 7   5    
Sofa    $0.07   100 7   3    
Stool   $1.00   0   7   5    
Natural wood    $0.00   99  7   20  
Carpet  $0.10   100 7   3
```

Comment: If you use sed for anything more than a simple s/old/new then you're using arcane, typically non-portable, constructs that became obsolete 40 years ago. Don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with NR (number of records) but need to delete blank lines.

```
   sed '/^$/d' filename | awk '{ORS=(NR%5?FS:RS)}1'
```